# A Case-Insensitive Prompt Not Working Even With The Use of toLowerCase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am learning JavaScript and have decided to do a basic Switch piece of code. I am trying to make my prompts' inputs case-insensitive using the .toLowerCase. However, that isn't working:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function(){
   var question = prompt("How do you do");
    switch(question) {
       case "Great".toLowerCase: 
          alert("Excellent!");
          break;
       case "Good".toLowerCase: 
          var question_2 = prompt("Could it be better?");
         if(question_2 == "yes") {
           alert("Well lets hope tomorrow is better!")     
         }
         else {
           alert("Phew! You got me for a moment!")   
         }
         break;
       case "Bad".toLowerCase:
          var q_3=prompt("What happened!");
         if(q_3) {
           alert("I hope tomorrow is better!");
         }
         else {
          alert("I didn't quite get that..");
         }
         break;
       default: alert("I didn't understand...");
     }
  }
```

Every time I insert text, correct or incorrect, I will always get "I didn't understand", which I believes that any input is wrong. E.g, if I insert into the 'question' prompt "great" or "Great" or even "GREAT", I will always get "I didn't understand" as an alert. Any help?

Comment: You must convert the prompt into lower case and the cases in lower case directly.   ``var question = prompt("How do you do").toLowerCase();``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. You need to be calling toLowerCase() on the question, not on the values question is being compared to.  That way if the user types "GrEaT" it will be converted to "great" before being checked against your string literals.
2. toLowerCase is a method.  So it must be called with () at the end.  If you're calling the method on variable 'x', your code would be x.toLowerCase().
3. The case conditions also need to be in lowercase so that they'll match the lowercase question, for instance "Great" needs to be "great".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toLowerCase()` method in your return result from the `prompt` instead.

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {
  var question = prompt("How do you do") || "";

  switch(question.toLowerCase()) {
     case "great": 
        alert("Excellent!");
        break;
     case "good": 
        var question_2 = prompt("Could it be better?") || "";
       if(question_2.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
         alert("Well lets hope tomorrow is better!")     
       }
       else {
         alert("Phew! You got me for a moment!")   
       }
       break;
     case "bad":
        var q_3 = prompt("What happened!") || "";
       if(q_3) {
         alert("I hope tomorrow is better!");
       }
       else {
        alert("I didn't quite get that..");
       }
       break;
     default: alert("I didn't understand...");
   }

};
```

HTH.

Comment: what if prompt is cancelled? `question` will be null and throw error

Comment: @charlietfl Nice catch! I've edited my answer. Thnx.

Comment: The lowercase value would never reach any of the case conditions